# How to suppress the headings output of a SQL query that returns no row

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying to do is this. Set up a SQL job that will query the database every hour looking for bad integers (-1s or zeros). Then put the output into an email and send the results to the dev team. I'm searching 80+ tables. If a particular table has no errors, IE no -1s, 0s or NULLs, and therefore returns no rows, I want to suppress the headings as well. I don't want to email a form full of headings if there are no problems. I know that I could do an "IF EXISTS" "ROWCOUNT >0" but that requires running each query twice. Once to see if it returns rows, and if true, again to get the results. Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: why not set up a trigger on the table to look for the bad integers?

Comment: Put the results of your initial query into a temp table, then count that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not cache each of your queries in a new table?  From there you could SELECT the non-zero rows and print your report.

Answer (score 0):

After due consideration and soliciting input from the team, I will just use the "IF EXISTS" method. We all despise triggers, and using the temp table method would generate a temp table even if all was well and nothing returned any rows. Using "IF EXISTS" will only run the query the second time if it returns results the first time. The idea being to find all the bugs that generate -1s, 0s, and NULLs. After a while it should run and produce no results anyway.